# What is Ord type?

Tags: haskell

Is every class not a type in Haskell :

```
Prelude> :t max
max :: Ord a => a -> a -> a
Prelude> :t Ord

<interactive>:1:1: Not in scope: data constructor ‘Ord’
Prelude>
```

Why does this not print `Ord` type signature ?

Comment: A class is not a type (at least not in the sense you are probably expecting). But also if you wanted to find out about a type, you'd use `:k` or `:i`. `:t` tells you the type of a value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay, there's a couple of things going on here.

First when you write `:t Ord` you're looking for something called `Ord` in the **value** namespace; specifically it would have to be a constructor, since the name starts with a capital letter.

Haskell keeps types and values completely separate; there is no relationship between the name of a type and the names of a type's constructors. Often when there's only one constructor, people will use the same name as the type. An example being `data Foo = Foo Int`. This declares *two* new named entities: the type `Foo` and the constructor `Foo :: Int -> Foo`.

It's not really a good idea to think of it as just making a type `Foo` that can be used both in type expressions and to construct `Foo`s. Because also common are declarations like `data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a`. Here there are 2 different constructors for `Maybe a`, and `Maybe` isn't a name of anything at all at the value level.

So just because you've seen `Ord` in a type expression doesn't mean that there is a name `Ord` at the value level for you to ask the type of with `:t`. Even if there were, it wouldn't necessarily be related top the type-level name `Ord`.

The second point that needs clarifying is that no, classes are not in fact types. A class is a *set* of types (which all support the interface defined in the class), but it is not a type itself.

In vanilla Haskell type classes are just "extra" things. You can declare them with a `class` declaration, instantiate them with an `instance` declaration, and use them in special syntax attached to types (the stuff left of the `=>` arrow) as constraints on type variables. But they don't really interact with the rest of the language, and you cannot use them in the main part of a type signature (the stuff right of the `=> arrow).

However, with the `ConstraintKinds` extension on, type classes *do* become ordinary things that exist in the type namespace, just like `Maybe`. They are still not types in the sense that there can never be any values that have them as types, so you can't use `Ord` or `Ord Int` as an argument or return type in a function, or have a `[Ord a]` or anything like that.

In that they are a bit like type constructors like `Maybe`. `Maybe` is a name bound in the type namespace, but it is not a *type* as such; there are no values whose type is just `Maybe`, but `Maybe` can be used as *part* of an expression defining a type, as in `Maybe Int`.

If you're not familiar with *kinds*, probably ignore everything I've said from `ConstraintKinds` onwards; you'll probably learn about kinds eventually, but they're not a feature you need to know much about as a beginner. If you are, however, what `ConstraintKinds` does is make a special kind `Constraint` and have type class constraints (left of the `=>` arrow) just be ordinary type-level things of kind `Constraint` instead of special purpose syntax. This means that `Ord` is a type-level thing, and we can ask it's kind with the `:k` command in GHCI:

```
Prelude> :k Ord
* -> Constraint
```

Which makes sense; `max` had type `Ord a => a -> a -> a`, so `Ord a` must have kind `Constraint`. If `Ord` can be applied to an ordinary type to yield a constraint, it must have kind `* -> Constraint`.

Comment: I wish we didn't use the word "type" in mutually contradictory ways such that "Maybe is not a type" and "Maybe is a higher-kinded type" can both be true statements.

Comment: Yes, we really need a less clunky term than "type-level thing" for "the things we can use in type expressions, whether or not they could be the types of values". Otherwise shorthand is inevitable. The context-dependency of the word "type" seems to work out fine for experts, but it makes it very difficult to pick this stuff up organically.

Answer (score 8):

`Ord` isn't a type; it's a typeclass. Typeclasses allow you to associate supported operations with a given type (somewhat similar to interfaces in Java or protocols in Objective-C). A type (e.g. `Int`) being an "instance" of a typeclass (e.g. `Ord`) means that the type supports the functions of the `Ord` typeclass (e.g. `compare`, `<`, `>` etc.).

You can get most info about a typeclass using `:i` in ghci, which shows you the functions associated with the typeclass and which types are instances of it:

```
ghci > :i Ord
class Eq a => Ord a where
  compare :: a -> a -> Ordering
  (<) :: a -> a -> Bool
  (>=) :: a -> a -> Bool
  (>) :: a -> a -> Bool
  (<=) :: a -> a -> Bool
  max :: a -> a -> a
  min :: a -> a -> a
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
instance Ord a => Ord (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘Data.Maybe’
instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Ord (Either a b)
  -- Defined in ‘Data.Either’
instance Ord Integer -- Defined in ‘integer-gmp:GHC.Integer.Type’
instance Ord a => Ord [a] -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
...
```

Answer (score 3):

`Ord` is not a type, but a [typeclass](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses#typeclasses-101).  It does not have a type, but a *kind*:

```
Prelude> :k Ord
Ord :: * -> Constraint
```

Typeclasses are one of the wonderful things about Haskell.  Check 'em out :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. You can impose type constraints, so `Ord a => a` is a type, but `Ord a` isn't. `Ord a => a` means "any type `a` with the constraint that it is an instance of `Ord`".

The error is because `:t` expects an expression. When GHCi tries to interpret `Ord` as an expression, the closest it can get to is a data constructor, since these are the only functions in Haskell that can start with capital letters.

Comment: @DanielWagner I think the point here was that because `:t` expects an expression, ghci has to interpret `Ord` as a data constructor: the only valid upper-case identifier to write after `:t` is a data constructor. So while I think it was poorly worded it's not totally out of place at the end of that sentence.

Comment: @DanielWagner good point, let me tweak my answer to shift the focus a bit.